# Filtering by frequency of observations per ID, for each month and each day - Pandas

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to filter my data frame [includes IDs, dates, time (these are the indexes) and other variables (no matter which)].

I want to filter the data frame by the frequency of the observations per ID, for each month and each day.

It means that, I want to stay with IDs that have at least 10 obs. **every** month, **and** at least 5 obs. **every** day, and to exclude those who don't meet the conditions.

Data illustration:

```
ID  date        time x  y
a   07/27/2019  ..  ..  ..
                ..  ..  ..
                ..  ..  ..
    08/27/2019  ..  ..  ..
                ..  ..  ..
                ..  ..  ..
                ..  ..  ..
                ..  ..  ..
                ..  ..  ..
b   06/28/2019  ..  ..  ..
                ..  ..  ..
                ..  ..  ..
                ..  ..  ..
                ..  ..  ..
                ..  ..  ..
    07/30/2019  ..  ..  ..
                ..  ..  ..
                ..  ..  ..
                ..  ..  ..
                ..  ..  ..
                ..  ..  ..
                ..  ..  ..
                ..  ..  ..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with count by [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html), compare and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
m = df.groupby(['ID', pd.Grouper(freq='M', key='date')])['date'].transform('size')
d = df.groupby(['ID','date'])['date'].transform('size')

print (df.assign(m = m, d = d))
   ID       date   time   x   y  m  d
0   a 2019-07-27  18:00  ..  ..  3  3
1   a 2019-07-27  18:00  ..  ..  3  3
2   a 2019-07-27  19:00  ..  ..  3  3
3   a 2019-08-27  20:00  ..  ..  6  6
4   a 2019-08-27  20:00  ..  ..  6  6
5   a 2019-08-27  20:00  ..  ..  6  6
6   a 2019-08-27  20:00  ..  ..  6  6
7   a 2019-08-27  20:00  ..  ..  6  6
8   a 2019-08-27  21:00  ..  ..  6  6
9   b 2019-06-28  18:00  ..  ..  6  6
10  b 2019-06-28  18:00  ..  ..  6  6
11  b 2019-06-28  18:00  ..  ..  6  6
12  b 2019-06-28  18:00  ..  ..  6  6
13  b 2019-06-28  18:00  ..  ..  6  6
14  b 2019-06-28  19:00  ..  ..  6  6
15  b 2019-07-30  08:00  ..  ..  8  8
16  b 2019-07-30  08:00  ..  ..  8  8
17  b 2019-07-30  08:00  ..  ..  8  8
18  b 2019-07-30  08:00  ..  ..  8  8
19  b 2019-07-30  08:00  ..  ..  8  8
20  b 2019-07-30  08:00  ..  ..  8  8
21  b 2019-07-30  09:00  ..  ..  8  8
22  b 2019-07-30  10:00  ..  ..  8  8

df = df[(m > 10) & (d > 5)]

print (df)
```

Comment: @qwerty - If test `print (m)` and if `print (d)` it return expected output in real data?

Comment: There should be at least 10 observations each month, not 10 observations in total. Also, at least 5 observations each day, and not 5 observations in total. If I print M and D, it shows how many observations there are in total for each ID.

Comment: @qwerty - Can you change data in sample with expected output?

Comment: I've edited the data. Let's say for simplicity, that the condition now is: Each ID must have at least 5 observations every month. So, after filtering the data above, we'll stay only with ID 'b', because ID 'a' doesn't have at least 5 observations in July.

Comment: @qwerty - Can you test now?